# Finding the derivative using first principles

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I go at finding the derivative of:

$f(x)=\frac{3x-1}{x+{2}},x≠-2  \mathbb{}$

using first principles?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could apply your definition of derivative.  What is that?

Comment: that's all the information the question gives me.

Comment: Do you know what a derivative is?   If not, you’re going to have a difficult time with this question

Comment: oh sorry, well I believe its the rate of change of a function?

Comment: @J.W. Tanner .. Ahh I didn't see. I will delay the answer. :)

Comment: Instantaneous rate of change.  Do you know a definition of derivative involving a limit?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straight forward actually. $f'(x)$ is defined according to the first principle as $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

\begin{align}
&f(x)=\frac{3x-1}{x+2}\\
&f(x+h)=\frac{3x+3h-1}{x+h+2}\\
&\implies \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{(3x-3h-1)(x+2)-(3x-1)(x+h+2)}{h}\\
&\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{7h}{h(x+h+2)(x+2)}\\
&=\frac{7}{(x+2)^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

For $x_0\ne2$ we have by definition of the derivative:
\begin{align}
f'(x_0) &= \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\\
&= \lim_{x\to x_0} \left(\frac{3x-1}{x+2} - \frac{3x_0-1}{x_0+2}\right)\cdot \frac1{x-x_0}\\
&= \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{(3x-1)(x_0+2)-(3x_0-1)(x+2)}{(x+2)(x_0+2)(x-x_0)}\\
&= \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{7(x-x_0)}{(x+2)(x_0+2)(x-x_0)}\\
&= \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac7{(x+2)(x_0+2)}\\
&= \frac7{(x+2)^2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The definition of derivative, applied to this function, is
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1{h} \left[ \frac{3(x+h)-1}{(x+h)+2}-\frac{3x-1}{x+2}\right]
$$
Cross multiply to get
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \left[ \frac{(x+2)(3x+3h-1)-(x+h+2)(3x-1)}{h(x+h+2)(x+2)}\right]\\
= \lim_{h\to 0} \left[ \frac{3x^2+3hx-x+6x+6h-2-3x^2+x-3hx+h-6x+2}{h(x+h+2)(x+2)}\right]\\
=  \lim_{h\to 0} \left[ \frac{3hx+6h-3hx+h}{h(x+h+2)(x+2)}\right]\\
=  \lim_{h\to 0} \left[ \frac{3x+6-3x+1}{(x+h+2)(x+2)}\right] \\
= \lim_{h\to 0} \left[ \frac{7}{(x+h+2)(x+2)}\right]
$$
Up to here we have not yet used the intention of taking $h \to 0$ but now we do, getting the answer 
$$
\frac7{(x+2)^2}
$$